# golang header line too long

Tags: golang

При попытке прочитать данные вылетает такая ошибка. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

```
b, e := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Прочитать ограниченное количество байт тоже не удается, ошибка та же

```
buff := make([]byte, 2048)
for {
  n, err := resp.Body.Read(buff)
  if err == io.EOF {
    break
  } else if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(buff[:n])
}
```

Сам ответ как я понимаю состоит из блоков : resp.TransferEncoding [chunked]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в ответе сервера, который не указывал длину контента, а движок golang видимо воспринимает такой ответ как длину -1 и chunked

Answer (score 0):

Обработчик ругается на то, что длина заголовка HTTP-запроса СЛИШКОМ ДЛИННАЯ. Т.е. заголовок такой несоразмерной длины задаётся на СТОРОНЕ СЕРВЕРА.